# Rails query where associated (joined) 'rich_text' is not nil/empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following right now, which works successfully to produce a list of users, with their `rich_text_tlk_with_me` 'rich_text' attachments.

```
User.joins(:rich_text_tlk_with_me).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5).order(created_at: :desc)
```

However, right now this query is also displaying users who have empty rich_text attachments.

I would like to run a query which only returns the users that have a non empty rich_text attachment.

I have tried:

```
User.joins(:rich_text_tlk_with_me).where.not(rich_text_tlk_with_me: [nil, ""]).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5).order(created_at: :desc)
```

But this did not return anything.

I have also searched for documentation, but not found anything relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `user has_many :rich_text_tlk_with_mes` and you are using Rails version > 5.

You can get all `users` who have a associated `rich_text_tlk_with_me` by the following query.

```
User.left_outer_joins(:rich_text_tlk_with_mes).where.not(rich_text_tlk_with_mes: {id: nil}).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5).order(created_at: :desc)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I actually realised that my query was working successfully (oops!), but not handling cases where the user deleted the content. Instead I am going to add a 'destroy attachment' route so then users who don't want to be listed can remove themselves. Thank you for helping though